# How to move an element into another transformed element in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

How to move 'affiliation' element into 'contrib' element which is in 'for-each' context in XSLT?

Input XML:

```
<article>
    <authors>Amrendra, Kumar; Mohan, Kumar</authors>
    <affiliation id="Amrendra, Kumar">Amrendra, Kumar</affiliation>
    <affiliation id="Mohan, Kumar">Mohan, Kumar</affiliation>
</article>
```

Current output:

```
<contrib-group>
  <contrib>
    <string-name>Amrendra, Kumar</string-name>
  </contrib>
  <contrib>
    <string-name>Mohan, Kumar</string-name>
  </contrib>
  <aff id="Amrendra, Kumar">Amrendra, Kumar</aff>
  <aff id="Mohan, Kumar">Mohan, Kumar</aff>
</contrib-group>
```

XSLT Code:

```
<xsl:template match="authors">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(node())"/>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <contrib-group>
                <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., ';')">
                <contrib>
                    <string-name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
                    </string-name>
                </contrib>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="../affiliation"/>
            </contrib-group>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Required Output: **(Matching with aff/@id and contrib/#pcdata)**

```
<contrib-group>
  <contrib>
    <string-name>Amrendra, Kumar</string-name>
    <aff id="Amrendra, Kumar">Amrendra, Kumar</aff>
  </contrib>
  <contrib>
    <string-name>Mohan, Kumar</string-name>
    <aff id="Mohan, Kumar">Mohan, Kumar</aff>
  </contrib>
</contrib-group>
```

when i try to apply 'affiliation' element inside contrib then it is showing below error:

```
[Saxon-PE 9.5.1.7] XPTY0020: Cannot select the parent of the context node: the context item is not a node
```

Comment: Can you show a complete XSLT that demonstrates your problem please? I don't think the template shown results in the error given, not unless your actual XSLT has the `<xsl:apply-templates select="../affiliation"/>` within the `xsl:for-each` structure, not after it. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly links between an author and the corresponding  `affiliation`? You have identical values in 3 places, it's hard to tell which pair to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `authors` string contains tokens identical to the values of `affiliation/@id`, you could do:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="aff" match="affiliation" use="@id" />

<xsl:template match="article">
    <xsl:variable name="current-article" select="." />
    <contrib-group>
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(authors, '; ')">
            <contrib>
                <string-name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </string-name>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('aff', ., $current-article)[node()]"/>
            </contrib>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </contrib-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="affiliation">
    <aff>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@* | node()" />
    </aff>
</xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get the required output.

Comment: Thank you. Now i got the result but always its coming with empty aff with @id. I have two more concern here:
1) if we have some data inside 'affiliation'. current logic make empty. 2) If 'affiliation' empty no need to generate 'aff'?

Comment: @AmrendraKumar I have made a couple of changes, see if that satisfies your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

```
<aff id="{.}">
    <xsl:value-of select="key('aff', ., $current-article)" />
</aff>
```

should be change with for avoiding spaces and missing values

```
<aff id="{normalize-space(.)}">
    <xsl:value-of select="key('aff', normalize-space(.), $current-article)" />
</aff>
```

Comment: Thank you!! I combined both of your comment then i got it. But i need one change again if 'affiliation' is empty (no PCDATA) then drop the 'affiliation'. Thanks again